# How to share Internet Connection in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I have a laptop1 which has its two interfaces ( wired and wireless ) working. And have another laptop (laptop2) for which only wired interface works.

I am planning to connect the two wired interfaces such that laptop2 can connect to internet through the wireless interface of laptop1. Any suggestions on how to achieve this? Both systems use Ubuntu 10.04 Desktop edition

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3063/share-wireless-connection-with-wired-ethernet-port/3143#3143) by [Owais Lone](https://askubuntu.com/users/214/owais-lone) should help you from ubuntu at the bottom of this page

> Right click the network manager and
>   click edit connections.  The under
>   Wired tab, Add a new connection. Under
>   the IPV4 Setting tab,  select "Shared
>   to others" for Method.
>
> Now other machines should connect to
>   LAN and get Internet access
>   automatically.

[image: Sharing internet over ethernet]

Also, look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing

Comment: How can I do this sharing using `/etc/network/interface`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your post that helped me to configured sharing wireless on ubuntu 12.04.
just want to add to it.  on ubuntu with internet connection, activate "My Share Connection".
on the other ubuntu without internet connection.  just use DHCP (which is by default).