# Networking: connect two machines

Tags: networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to share Internet Connection in Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/282891/how-to-share-internet-connection-in-ubuntu)

Hi all, I have a laptop1 which has its two interfaces ( wired and wireless ) working. and have another laptop (laptop2) for which only wired interface works. I am planning to connect the two wired interfaces such that laptop2 can connect to internet through the wireless interface of laptop1. Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: This does not belong here and also misses quite important details like the operating system you want to use...

Comment: Try superuser. You are on the wrong side of the internets.

Comment: dup of abovehttp://superuser.com/questions/282891/connecting-two-machines-running-on-ubuntu