# Access internet through another machine

Tags: ubuntu, internet-connection, socks-proxy, ssh-tunnel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to share Internet Connection in Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/282891/how-to-share-internet-connection-in-ubuntu)

I have two machines, both running Ubuntu. Both the machines are on a local network. I am behind a proxy server and am required to login for accessing internet. This means I can't access Internet on both machines simultaneously. What I want to do, is to be able to login on one machine and then route all my internet requests on other machine to the logged-in machine. I have administrator priviliges on both the machines. SSH tunneling does not seem to be doing the job even though every artice on the net is suggesting it.

Comment: Why "This means I can't access Internet on both machines simultaneously.". What does this proxy server exactly does? It is HTTP proxy? Does it capture all traffic to login form unless logged in?

Comment: Why does SSH tunnelling fail?

Comment: @Vi yes, it is an HTTP web proxy. I can't access Internet on both machines simultaneously as I can be logged in from only one machine at a time. 
Ssh tunnelling fails : I create the tunnel, and configure my browser, by pages don't open. The error message (on the terminal I mean) says error 3 connection refused. I can't find sufficient help on the Internet for this error message either

Comment: @tech I had gone through that previously, but it seems to require more than 1 networking device.

Comment: What is being "logged in"? Is it like HTTP authentication? Start your HTTP proxy (like polipo or squid or 3proxy) on one computer and use it from another.